# trying to create a line between two divs

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am trying to create a line that will go between two divs. Unfortunately I can't get the line to align its self vertically between the two divs. The image above is what I am currently getting. Below is the html.

```css
.line {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
.home {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.logout {
  width: 15%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="home">Home</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="logout">Reports &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button> <a href="web url"> log out </a> 
    </button>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have tried using an hr tag but I can't get that to work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox`

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.line {
  height: 2px;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="home">Home</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="logout">Reports
    <button> <a href="web url"> log out </a> </button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hah.  You beat me to it by like 10 seconds.  I took the time to type out my answer and submitted to see yours already here.  +1

Comment: @Chris Stanley Sorry about that `:)`

Comment: Thanks this works for me. So this will be compatible with everything except internet explorer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with flexbox yet (I recommend you become so and follow the answer posted by Nenad) and want another solution you can simply use `position: relative` on the `.line` and specify a top value.

Following code taken from the fiddle example you can find below:

```
.line {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 50px 0 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CZorio13/17ekyr8z/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**CSS:**

```
.line {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  width: 65%;
}

hr {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
}

.home {
  width: 20%;
  padding-left: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logout {
  width: 15%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section>
  <div class="home"> Home</div>
  <div class="line">
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="logout"> Reports &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button> <a href="web url"> log out </a> </button>
  </div>
</section>
```

See the live demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/dLpuqanh/)